# Handling keyboard input winapi

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc, keyboard-events, hwnd

Suddenly had to finish the old project and ran into problem with keyboard input handling. I have a window with a list of items. I want to select an item by pressing the first few letters of its name on the keyboard, as it works in the Windows. Search on the Internet, unfortunately, did not give results.
I have this code for processing messages and events.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDHELP, OnHelp)
    ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BEGIN_EVENTSINK_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)
    ON_EVENT(CMyDialog, SOME_ID, SOME_DISP_ID, SomeFunction, SOME_PARAMS)
END_EVENTSINK_MAP()
```

I would like to know if it is possible to add such functionality to it. 
 I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @VTT: `WM_CHAR` is the correct message to handle.

Comment: [Using Keyboard Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646268(v=vs.85).aspx)